# How to loop mysql tables that have default prefix using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prefix

I looked at [select from mysql db with 300 tables using a default prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340899/select-from-mysql-db-with-300-tables-using-a-default-prefix) but I still don't understand.

Here's my problem:
The database has 5 tables named as pbtest01, pbtest02, pbtest03, pbtest04 and pbtest05. I use the following code to loop the tables:

```
$x = 3;
for($k = 1; $k <= $x; $k++){

  $sql5 = "SELECT *
           FROM CONCAT('pbtest0',$k)
           WHERE id = '930820105627'
           ";

  $data5 = mysql_query($sql5) or die(mysql_error().$sql5);
  $list5 = mysql_fetch_array($data5);

  $var[$k] = $sql5['value'];
}

echo $var[1];
echo $var[2];
echo $var[3];
```

but get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'CONCAT('pbtest0',1) WHERE id = '930820105627'' at line 1
SELECT *
FROM CONCAT('pbtest0',1)
WHERE id = '930820105627'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not only PHP? `SELECT * FROM pbtest0{$k}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for($k = 1; $k <= $x; $k++){

   $sql5 = "SELECT *
            FROM pbtest0" . $k . "
            WHERE id = '930820105627'
            ";
   ...
}
```

`CONCAT()` is a MySQL function, and you need to build the table names in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `CONCAT()` for a table name. Instead, just build the string with PHP string concatenation or string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying your database incorrectly. Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM 'pbtest0".$k."' WHERE id='930820105627'"
```

This will put the single quotes around the correct string remove the unneeded `CONCAT()` function.